# Possible to preload and render an Angular2-view invisibly upon hover?

Tags: angular, optimization, hover, preload

Is it possible to preload and -render a view invisbly upon hover?

I have an app that lists items. Each item is its own component and when you click any of these items, it gets replaced with a detailed view (another component) of the same item. Something like this:

```
<app-item-preview [id]="1" *ngIf="!shouldShowDetailView(1)">
Click to unfold item #1. Upon hovering this item, app-item-detail should be preloaded and prerendered but not yet shown.
</app-item-preview>

<app-item-detail [id]="1" *ngIf="shouldShowDetailView(1)">
This view contains images and lots of content for item #1 and should be pre-rendered upon hovering the app-item-preview-component to minimize latency.
</app-item-detail>
```

I checked with the dev-tools and it's the dom rendering of this complicated detail view that introduces the most latency between the click and the finished component being rendered. I was wondering if it would be possible to make Angular render this view hidden already when the user hovers it and then simply display it when he/she clicks it?

In addition to rendering the dom elements, the detail view might containt an  embedded YouTube-player and some images that are loaded from server. Loading everything upon hover would speed up the app very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key for you is that you need to use two different properties for your `<app-item-detail>`. Your `*ngIf` should look at if the details should be shown or the content should be pre-rendered. You should additionally make use of setting the `display` property to `none` if the details should not be shown yet. Something like the following:

```html
<app-item-preview [id]="1" *ngIf="!shouldShowDetailView(1)" (hover)="preRenderDetailView(1)" (click)="showDetailView(1)">
    Click to unfold item #1. Upon hovering this item, app-item-detail should be preloaded and prerendered but not yet shown.
</app-item-preview>

<app-item-detail [id]="1" *ngIf="shouldShowDetailView(1) || shouldPreRenderDetailView(1)" [style.display]="shouldShowDetailView(1) ? '' : 'none'">
    This view contains images and lots of content for item #1 and should be pre-rendered upon hovering the app-item-preview-component to minimize latency.
</app-item-detail>
```

Comment: Really good idea! But doesn't display: none cause elements not to render at all? I read about techniques where you use some rect clipping or moving the element to -9999px absolute position to hide them when you want them to render but not show. I'll try these out and post back. Thanks so far! :)